# Changing condition statement from x >= 0 to x > 0

Tags: python

Just going through a Python 3.x self-study book. I've got a basic code, which allows user to enter a sequence of nonnegative int. When the user inputs a negative int, the sequence stops and a result is printed. It looks like that:

```
entry = 0
sum = 0
print("Enter numbers to sum, negative number ends list: ")

while entry >= 0:
    entry = int(input())
    if entry >= 0:
        sum += entry
print("Sum =", sum)
```

Now I got to a exercise questions part of the book. It asks if the condition of the if statement could have used

```
>
```

instead of

```
>=
```

Also if the condition of the while loop could use 
`>`

instead of

`>=`.

I have obviously tried both combinations and noticed that the > could be used in the if condition instead of >=, which would not affect the program. But if I would swap the >= for > in while statement the program would stop right after running it, showing Sum=0, not allowing the user to input any integers. Why swapping if condition doesn't change anything, but swapping while condition affects the program?

Comment: `entry` starts as zero. If the `while` condition requires `entry > 0`, then the loop will never be entered.

Comment: Do you understand what the task of the `while` loop is, in this context?

Comment: You commenters should read the question carefully.

Comment: For these kind of questions [Pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) is a great tool to understand, why things happen.

Comment: Aside: it's considered bad form to use the name of a builtin function (especially one as common and useful as `sum`) for your own object.  If your guide recommended that name, I'd be a little doubtful of its grasp of Python style.  (It still might be very useful in many other ways, of course.)

Comment: The variable name sum, you have mentioned it's a very good point, but the guide in general is a great source of knowledge. BTW, will try the Pythontutor website next time, it seems powerful.

Answer (score 1):

If you read each statement in sequence, you can probably see what happens:

```
entry = 0
```

Entry is zero ...

```
while entry > 0:
```

While entry is larger than zero, do this ..

But since entry isn't larger than zero, the while loop never runs. The statement is checked before the loop is invoked the first time, so your program continues with the next statement (`print`) instead.

When you have `>=`, you also allow the value 0 - so "While entry is larger than, or equal to, zero" allows the loop to run.

Comment: Thanks very much for not yelling at me right away :). I think I got the point now. I was also wondering why changing the >= to > in the if statements does not affect the program, but I believe it actually does, but I can't see it happening in the command. So when the condition is >=, the statement adds int value 0 to the variable sum, but when the condition is > the condition is not met, so nothing is added to the variable sum. Am I wright?

Comment: Hey, the question is if `>` can be used in the `if` statement and not `while` loop :D

Comment: Actually you're right. But I was going to ask both :(

Comment: So I've answered both

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
if entry >= 0:
    sum += entry
```

into

```
if entry > 0:
    sum += entry
```

won't change the behavior of the program since adding 0 to any number doesn't change the value.
Changing `while entry >= 0` into `while entry > 0` would break the program because the loop would never be entered with the intialization of `entry = 0`.

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it is what you were looking for . Good luck ;)